# How to apply a CSS class on ItemTemplate eval

Tags: c#, webforms

I have gridview with ItemTemplate that i want to apply bootstrap class on Label

When the Status is open i want to apply this class `class="badge badge-success"` and when it is Close i want to apply this class `class="badge badge-danger"`

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status">
            <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:Label ID="lblStatus" runat="server" Text='<%# ((string)Eval("Status") == "Open") ? "Open" : "Closed" %>'></asp:Label>
             </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: ASP.NET web controls have a CssClass property which you can set to apply a css class to the HTML element it writes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `class` property:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status">
    <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:Label ID="lblStatus" runat="server" 
class='<%# ((string)Eval("Status") == "Open") ? "badge badge-success" : "badge badge-danger" %>'
Text='<%# ((string)Eval("Status") == "Open") ? "Open" : "Closed" %>'></asp:Label>
     </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```